# Why am I getting a link error for a template class in 64-bit build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

Using Visual Studio 2015 we are converting a suite of dlls and exes from 32-bit build to 64-bit.

We have a static library that includes a template class that extends CTypedPtrArray (call the extension MyPtrArray).  I have successfully built the static library in 64-bit.

A dll that consumes the static lib defines a class (call it Class A) and a second class (call it Class B); Class B is derived from MyPtrArray:
class B:public MyPtrArray<A*>

No problems in a 32-bit build, but a 64-bit build of the consuming dll results in link errors pointing to methods in MyPtrArray.  Those methods are defined and implemented in the static library in MyPtrArray.h and MyPtrArray.cpp.

I am forcing instantiation of MyPtrArray:
#include "MyPtrArray.cpp"
template MyPtrArray<A*>;

Any advice/thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me the specifics of this error? If it is convenient, could you please provide the relevant code? This helps solve the problem.

Comment: I am constrained as to how much code detail I can provide, and I fully understand if this makes it difficult or impossible to answer my question.  The error is "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall MyPtrArray<class A *>::<method name>(class A * const)const " <decorated signature>".  LNK2001, of course, says that the compiler can't find the definition of <method name>.

Comment: Apparently I was unclear in my description.  I do have source code for all involved dlls/libs and am building 64-bit versions.  I get the link error during the 64-bit build.

Comment: To be honest, it is difficult for me to help you solve this problem without specific code. Maybe provide a Minimal Reproducible Example would help for answering your question.  I suggest that you could check the `MyPtrArray` . Or you could check if the lib you link is 64-bit and re-add the lib.